# How to choose a relationship for tables in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-5, foreign-key-relationship, database-relations

I have created three tables:

```
Student(ID, username), Teacher(ID, name) and Rating(ID, rating)
```

On my Rating table I want to record student's rating to a particular teacher. Each student can rate a teacher exactly once. He can rate other teachers but not the same teacher.

In this case, which relationship will suit better? I am a newbie in Laravel.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great questions tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community.  
A good place to start is adding a [mcve] for others to troubleshoot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each student can rate a teacher only once, the most straightforward would be to add `student_id` and `teacher_id` columns to `Rating` table and use them as foreign keys in the relationship.

Then you can define the relationship in Student model:

```
class Student extends Model
{
 ... 
    // Ratings given by the student
    public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Rating');
    }
}
```

and Teacher model:

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
 ... 
    // Ratings received by the teacher
    public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Rating');
    }
}
```

Read more on one-to-many relationships:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Right one to many suits well for my requirement. Could you just explain me a bit about what all I need to do after defining relationship on my model?

Comment: That depends on what you need to have done. Try formulating that as a specific question. This is really not the place for giving you a complete tutorial. There are better sources for such information, e.g. https://laracasts.com/

Comment: Ok. Anyways thanks for ur help